# Degree theory and Invariance of domain

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

We'll use the Proposition (F) to show that:

*(Invariance of domain) Let $f: M \to N$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; furthermore, $N$ is connected.
If $f$ is injective then $f$ is a open map.*

dem: We can assume that $f$ is locally proper by [$f:M→Y$ $C^{1}$ map between manifolds $M$ e $N$ with dimension m and n respectively then $f$ is locally proper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753360/f-m-to-y-c1-map-between-manifolds-m-e-n-with-dimension-m-and-n?lq=1).

Let $x \in M$, and $y:=f(x) \in N$ with $(U,\phi)$ chart in $M$ of $x$ and $(V,\psi)$ chart in $N$ of $f(x)$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$ is proper. Let $B(\psi(y), \epsilon) \subseteq \psi(V)$ 
so  $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$ is a open  connected subset of $N$. Since $f$ is continous, exist $W$ open in $M$ such that $W \subseteq U$ and $f(W) \subseteq \psi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \epsilon)$.

Let  $B(\phi(x), \delta) \subseteq \phi(W)$ so $\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta)$ is a open  connected subset of $M$ such that

$f(\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta)) \subseteq  \psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$.

Note that $\tilde{f} = f|_{\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta)}: \phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta) \to  \psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$  is injective proper mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$, where 
where $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$ is connected. Then by (F) $\tilde{f}$ is surjective. So $f( \phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta))$ is open, and we finished.

**In this solution has a problem:** I'd take $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon + \xi)$  and the result continous true, so $\tilde{f}$  is a bijecion of $\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta)$ to  $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$ and $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon +\xi)$, and it's false.

Where am I missing???

Thank you.

---

We have that:

Definition (A):

Let $f: M \to N$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; and $x$ is a regular point of $f$.
So $df_{x}$ is a linear isomorphism. If  $f$ preserves (resp. reverse) orientation at $x$  we denote $sing_{x}(f) = +1$ (resp. $-1$).

(Mapping Degree, Ruiz, 2009. p. 86)

Proposition (B):

Let $f: M \to N$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; and $y$ is a regular value of $f$.
so $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite set and $d(f,y)= \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} sign(df_{x})$.

(Mapping Degree, Ruiz, 2009. p. 95)

Proposition (C):

Let $f: M \to N$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; furthermore, $N$ is connected.
Then the integer $d(f,y)$ does not depend on the choice of regular valeu $y$. It is called the degree of $f$ an is denoted by $deg(f)$.

(Mapping Degree, Ruiz, 2009. p. 99)

Corollary (D):

Let $f: M \to N$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; furthermore, $N$ is connected.
If the $deg(f) \neq 0$ then $f$ is surjective  map.

(Mapping Degree, Ruiz, 2009. p. 99)

Proposition (E):

If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $C^{1}$ locally injective and $U$ is a open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then the set of the points $x \in U$
such that $df_{x}$ is injective is open  and dense in $U$.

dem: By $rank$ $theorem$.

Proposition (F):

Let $f: M \to N$ $C^{1}$ be a proper smooth mapping of two oriented, boundaryless, smooth manifolds of dimension $m$; furthermore, $N$ is connected.
If $f$ is injective then  $f$ is surjective.

dem: Let $(U,\phi)$ chart in $M$. By (E) there exists $x \in U$ such that $df_{x}$ is injective, so $df_{x}$ is a isomorphism linear. So $y=f(x)$ is regular value, 
and since $f$ is injective we have that $d(f,y) \neq 0$. So by (D), we have that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of invariance of domain doesn't work, because you have given no justification that $\tilde{f}$ is proper.  In fact, it probably won't be proper.  Indeed, if (as you suggest) you replace $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon+\xi$ for some $\xi>0$, then $\tilde{f}$ will definitely not be proper, since $\psi^{-1}(\overline{B(\psi(y), \epsilon)})$ is a compact subset of $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon+\xi))$ containing the image of $\tilde{f}$, but the domain of $\tilde{f}$ is not compact.

To fix the proof, you need to be much more careful in choosing the domain of $\tilde{f}$.  You can take the domain of $\tilde{f}$ to be $f^{-1}(\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)))$: then $\tilde{f}$ will be proper because $f$ was.  (Properness of a map is preserved if you restrict the range to a subset $A$ and the domain to $f^{-1}(A)$.)  To conclude that $\tilde{f}$ (and hence $f$) is open, you then need to use the fact that a proper continuous bijection between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hi. About the first paragraph, $\tilde{f} = f|_{\phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta)}: \phi^{-1}(B(\phi(x), \delta) \to  \psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon) $ is proper.

Let $K$ compact in $\psi^{-1}(B(\psi(y), \epsilon)$, so $K$ is closed. By continuous of $\tilde{f}$, we have that $\tilde{f}^{-1}(K)$ is closed. So $\phi(\tilde{f}^{-1}(K))$ is closed, 
but $\phi(\tilde{f}^{-1}(K)) \subseteq B(\phi(x), \delta)$ bounded set, so $\phi(\tilde{f}^{-1}(K))$ is compact, then  $\tilde{f}^{-1}(K)$ is compact, and $\tilde{f}$ is proper.

Comment: You know that $\phi(\tilde{f}^{-1}(K)) \subseteq B(\phi(x), \delta)$ is closed in $B(\phi(x), \delta)$, but why is it closed in all of $\mathbb{R}^m$?  You need to know that in order to conclude it is compact.

Comment: In last paragraph to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is open can we change the fact that "a proper continuous bijection between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism" by proposition (F) ?

Comment: No, proposition (F) is what gives you that $\tilde{f}$ is a bijection, but you still have to do some additional work to conclude it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hi, I found a result due Smale that showed that $f$ is locally proper. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753360/f-m-to-y-c1-map-between-manifolds-m-e-n-with-dimension-m-and-n

Comment: So $f$ is locally proper, hence there exist other reason to justify the wrong argument

Comment: What is your definition of "locally proper"?  I'm not sure exactly what the definition should be, but it definitely shouldn't mean that you can restrict the domain however you want and still get a proper map.